# How to make a controller method private and accessible only to a specific service in Service Fabric?

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-service-fabric

I have two services running in my Service Fabric cluster. Let's assume they are Service A and Service B, both of them are Stateless Services. I am using the dns service method to communicate between A and B and the entry point in B is an api which has a route. Now this route is also publicly accessible since I have exposed port 80 publicly for that service. And even though someone who is trying to access this api will have to send the appropriate Auth tokens, I still don't want to be able to anyone outside the cluster to access this api. Is there any other way I can achieve what I am trying to do? I know another way is to use the service proxy pattern but for some reason that did not work for me.

Comment: Can't you just run Service B under a different port than 80?

Comment: Even if I do that the api is going to be publicly accessible. I ended up using the service proxy method pattern which service fabric offers and that solved my problem.

Comment: When you configure the reverse proxy's port in Load Balancer, all microservices in the cluster that expose an HTTP endpoint are addressable from outside the cluster